# Facebook api feed : how post message in a single user wall?

Tags: facebook

I use facebook SDK javascript to post a message from a website to my wall on facebook.
When I post, I can choose the users who can read my message.

Can I change the script to send a message directly to one or any users automatically?

Answer (score 0):

To send a private message through facebook API is not intended behavior.  to prevent spam it is assumed.  This can be overcome by sending an email to `facebook_username@facebook.com` and it will appear as an instant message to the user.  This is NOT an intended solution however and it is EXPRESSLY discouraged in the facebook docs.